# Components start out overlapping then move when window is resized

Tags: javascript, css, rally, overlap

I am writing a Rally app that has both a chart and a grid in separate Rally containers. The containers are in a 'vbox' (vertical box) layout. They are set up like:

```css
{
    xtype: 'container',
    itemId: 'rightView',
    flex: 1,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'topRightView',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'bottomRightView',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

where the chart is in the topRightView and the grid is in the bottomRightView

When they are first rendered, the grid completely overlaps the chart. However, when I resize the window at all, they go to the places that they are supposed to be (with the chart positioned above the grid).

The css for the grid and the chart is:

```css
.builds-grid {
    width:600px;
}

.builds-chart {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: dotted;
    width: 700px;
}
```

After inspecting both the chart and the grid html, I found that the position of both is relative, so that should not be messing it up.

I also tried putting different z-indexes on the two to make sure they don't overlap, but that has not worked.

The grid is rendered before the chart, so this could possibly be part of the problem. I don't really know what to do about it; any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your top code segment, add this line:

```
height: 400px,
```

into the container that will be holding the chart.  It should end up looking something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    itemId: 'rightView',
    flex: 1,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'topRightView',
            height: 400px,
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'bottomRightView',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
}
```